# What is the best and most straighforward way to start a GUI application via a HTTP request?

Tags: windows, perl, http, user-interface

What is the best and most straighforward way to start a GUI application via a HTTP request?

This question is specific to a windows server and the GUI application is likely to be running as the local `SYSTEM` user. The HTTP request will be from outside of the servers network i.e. over the web.

I've tried making use of PHP and failed miserably, anything else that I can try?

Thanks all

### Update

I tried the perl suggestion but it seems to run the app in the background:

```
#!C:/Perl/bin/perl.exe
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";

$ExecString = 'Start C:/www/csharp/Test.exe 8998 "Test Message"';

exec $ExecString;
```

Comment: What webserver are you using? IIS? Apache?

Comment: Running a GUI application == running a CLI application AFAICT. I've done this with Python, but on Linux. Maybe a Python script would be more scalable than PHP, as there are quite a few web frameworks which could suit your needs more than just PHP.

Comment: @0A0D - I am happy to use any web server, I was using Apache for PHP but ran into trouble. @Blender - I don't think running a GUI application is the same as a CLI app. The application in question has its own window and menu etc - is that what you mean too?

Comment: Are you going to show this to the user? Why not use a Java Applet?

Comment: @0A0D - no this will not be shown to users, they are going to get an email of screenshots of my application working. They don't need to see it, they just need to say one or two screenshots of the state its in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a CGI binary.  Run it from the web-server.  Have the binary start your application.

A Perl script will do the job, too.

The CGI/perl/whatever will need to have appropriate local permissions, or the OS will forbid it to start an application.

Comment: I've just tried this but it seems to run the application in the background and not the foreground. See my update.

Comment: I'n not sure what you mean; an application which opens a GUI, opens a GUI - the window will be there.  Do you mean it doesn't take the focus?

Comment: If that is the problem, there standard API functions in Windows which make a window come to the front and take the focus.  Your application may need to use them.  If you can't change the application, there are utilities which send instructions to windows as if the user had clicked on their title bar, etc, so you can have the window automatically brought to the front/given the focus, etc.  You'll need to run that little utility too - make a batch file and run that from the CGI.